# document.write is behaving weirdly in Youtube videobar's javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, youtube-javascript-api

Youtube's Videobar is an outdated widget. Google is still serving the js but the documentation and links have been taken off from their site. You can see a running example of this over at: sicmaui.com (right side, youtube tab)

Its currently being loaded using a script tag on html

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/uds/api?file=uds.js&v=1.0&source=uds-vbw" type="text/javascript"></script>
GSearch.setOnLoadCallback(somefunction); //works
```

But it doesn't work when I try to load this using the following code

```
var $script = $('<script></script>').attr('src', src).bind('load', function(){
GSearch.setOnLoadCallback(somefunction); //GSearch is undefined
});
$('head')[0].appendChild($script[0]);
```

Now the js is being loaded perfectly fine. But the variable is undefined. 
I digged into the google's js and found that later on its loading another js file using this code:

```
google.loader.writeLoadTag("script", google.loader.ServiceBase + "/api/search/1.0/8c68537a8c14de310f268bd7f81c9c67/default+en.I.js", false);
```

which makes a call (where 'n' equals document)

```
n.write('<script src="' + b + '" type="text/javascript"><\/script>')
```

Now ideally this js should overwrite the entire page contents with this script. But for some reason it isn't doing so and this is driving me nuts!

Either way, my primary goal is to load this file asynchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using [jQuery's `getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/); it handles all the mess you don't want to be involved in: adding the `async` attribute, defining both `readystatechange` and `load` event handlers, avoiding memory leaks, …

### Edit:

As for your root problem: I don't think that you can make this script work if you load it asynchronously. `document.write` is synchronous by nature. See this related question: [Warning: A call to document.write() from an asynchronously-loaded external script was ignored. How is this fixed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811985/warning-a-call-to-document-write-from-an-asynchronously-loaded-external-scrip)

Comment: I tried that as well. It's still the same. What I can't seem to figure out is why the n.write (document.write) inside the google's code is not working as it should.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have read your question more thoroughly; see my edited answer.

Comment: ahh..that explains the weird behavior! Thanks Julien for clearing that out